# C: About typedef and enum

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I just started to learn C, and I think I didn't fully understand the use of typedef.

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum _season{spring=1, summer, autumn, winter} season;

int main()
{
    int val;
    printf(" enter the number of the season: ");
    scanf("%d", &val);

    season = val;

    switch (season) {
        case 1:
            printf("spring");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("summer");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("autumn");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("winter");
            break;
        default:
            printf("the seasons are only 4");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works without typedef. I've saw some example using typedef, and some not using it, so now I'm a bit confused, and I don't understand when I should use typedef, and when not?

Can you give me a quick explanation please?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: uppercase letters and format in code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

typedef defines a new data type. So you can have:

```
typedef char* my_string;
typedef struct{
  int member1;
  int member2;
}my_struct
```

So now you can declare variables with these new data types

```
my_string s;
my_struct x;

s = "welcome";
x.member1 = 10;
```

For Enum, things are a bit different - consider the following examples:

```
enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND};
int main()
{
   int data = 20;
   if (data == FIRST)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

enum is a integer type; first value in the enum is 0 (unless otherwise specified) second is the first value+1 (0+1 in this case) and so on. When you declare a variable of type enum_data_type, you can only assign it values which exist in the enum....the compiler does the verification.
so here in theexample,`if(data==FIRST) is false`

using typedef enum prevents other values being added to the enum:

```
typedef enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND} Order;
int main()
{
   Order data = 20;   //ERROR 20 is not a Order
   if (data == FIRST)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: "`typedef` defines a new data type" No. It just defines an alias for an type. C uses compatibility by structure, not by name/typedef.

Comment: @Olaf i understand what you mean but does not  that alias work as a datatype and what i found that a lot of places it is mentioned in a same way see this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm

Comment: Just read the standard about [type compatibility](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7). This is the only mandatory reference. However, please read the first sentence of your linked tutorial very carefully. It exactly states what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It is clear now. Yes it defines an alias and a not a new type, but you example helped me to understand better. thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many uses of `typedef`s. To quote a few

> 1) `typedef`s can be used to make programs easy to port. If `typedef`s are used for data types that may be machine-independent, onle the `typedef`s need to be changed when the program is moved.

---

> 2) It can be used to provide better documentation for a program. A type called `Treeptr` may be easier to understand then one declared only as a pointer to a complicated structure.

Source: [The C programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)

Answer (score -1):

Don't you mix up typedef and define ? If you do :

when you use define, you need to specify values corresponding to your text (not always numeric), by using enum, values are going to be associated automatically. If so, you shouldn't use numerical values in your switch but the text you defined